# Codeigniter check if user exists in database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check that if the user exists in the database or not. I have a method in my Model which is as follows:  I create a new `user`, insert `id` and `password` from posted data and then pass the `id` to the function to check whether a user with this `id` exists or not. But it gives the following error:

---

> `Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined property: Login::$User
>   Filename: controllers/login.php
>   Line Number: 56
>   Fatal error: Call to a member function user_exists() on a non-object in F:\xamp\htdocs\leoSMS\application\controllers\login.php on line 56
>   Model name : User`

---

### The user check function

```
public function user_exists($id){
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query = $this ->db->get('user_table');

if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return TRUE;
else    
    return FALSE;
}
```

---

### The Controller

```
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller 
{
    /**  
     * load the magazines
     */
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('User','National_Holiday','Updated_Holiday');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('login'); 
    }

    /** 
     * add a magazine
     */
    public function login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(array (
        array(
           'field'  => 'username',
           'label' => 'username',
           'rules' => 'required|is_numeric|max_length[1]|min_length[1]',
           ) ,
        array(
           'field'  => 'password',
           'label' => 'password',
           'rules' => 'required|is_numeric|max_length[1]|min_length[1]',
           ),   
        ));

        $this -> form_validation ->set_error_delimiters(
            '<div class="alert alert-error">','</div>');

        echo $this->input->post('username') . "<br>";
        echo $this->input->post('password'). "<br>";

        $user = new User();
        $user->user_id = $this->input->post('username');
        $user->password = $this->input->post('password');
        echo "<tt><pre>". var_dump($user) . "</tt></pre>";

        if($this->User->user_exists($user->user_id))
            echo "true";
        else {
            echo "false";
        }

        if(!$this->form_validation->run()){
           $this->load->view('login');
        }
       else {
           $this->load->view('national_holiday_screen');
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if($user->user_exists($user->user_id))` instead of `if($this->User->user_exists($user->user_id))`

Your statement is trying to execute a method of an unknown property User. Probably the uses is not defined as a property of class Login.
The new statement is calling the method of an object of class User. This object exists because you have just created it.

Comment: Please edit your answer to add an explanation of how your code works and how it solves the OP's problem. Many SO posters are newbies and will not understand the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

try this  model class

```
function create_member()/** function to create the new user **/
{
    $this->db->where('Username ', $this->input->post('Username '));
    $query = $this->db->get('register');
    if($query->num_rows > 0)
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-error"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><strong>';
        echo "Username already taken";  
        echo '</strong></div>';
    }
}
```